# Storing repository object identification -- in code or configuration?

Tags: c#, automation, watin, ui-automation

We are working on automation various different web/client applications, using several different frameworks (WatiN, Ranorex for example).

My question is -- what are the for/against for storing the actual object identification (the properties used to identify it at runtime) in the code (using attributes or whatever other mechanism), or extracting it to an external configuration file that will be read by the code executing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Storing the object identification mechanism in code would

1. require a rebuild if there are any changes.

but at the same time would

1. make debugging and maintenance easier
2. is compelling, neat and elegant :)

Storing the object identification in configuration or a test data file would lead to an additional step that will retrieve the object identifiers from the file.

~Ashish Narmen